# Keeping the list element names after subsetting in R

Tags: r, function, subset

Suppose I have a list of 2 named `data.frame`s. The name of first `data.farme` is `Study1`, and the name of second `data.frame` is `Study2` (as shown below).

When I use `subset` below, I lose the `Study1` or `Study2` which are names of my data.frames?

I was wondering if there is a way to subset from these data.frames while keeping the names of them?

```
a <- list(Study1 = data.frame(d = 6:8, long = c(T, F, T)), Study2 = data.frame(d = 9:11, long = c(T, T, F)) )

subset(a[[1]], long == T)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `subset` parameter of `subset` to filter the rows based on the 'long' column.  As 'long' is `logical`, there is no need for `==`

```
lapply(a, subset, subset = long)
```

---

In addition to the `if/else` condition, other option is `swtich` if there are many values

```
dd <- function(a, val = "long") {
      switch(val,
            "long" = lapply(a, subset, subset = long),
            "short" = lapply(a, subset, subset = !long)
      )


}

dd(a1, "short")
```

#### data

```
a1 <- list(Study1 = data.frame(d = 6:8, long = c(T, F, T)),
           Study2 = data.frame(d = 9:11, long = c(T, T, F)) )
```

Comment: @rnorouzian  This is what I get `warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In if (!is.na(long)) nm <- if (long) "long" else "short" :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (long) "long" else "short" :.`

Comment: @rnorouzian  May be you need `ifelse`, but it willl return the same length.  If you need only one value, then probably `any` or `all`,